# UILabel Auto Sizing Issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel, uifont

I am having a Custom tableview cell with Two label. The label having the Custom Font.
When I rotate the Device the Space between two label increases.

I have used the Flexible left, top and width auto sizing mask in both the Label.

[image: IN Portrait Shows Fyn]

[image: In Lanscape Space issues]